# Understanding why regex in NSPredicate isn't working when it should

Tags: objective-c, regex, nspredicate

I have a `regex` that I am trying to test, and it seems that according to the [ICU specs](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp) it should match:

```
NSString *s = @"Asterisk 39 - S*W*A*G Geo-Art";
NSString *re = @".*Geo";
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", re];
NSLog(@"Match: %@", [p evaluateWithObject:s] ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

It evaluates as **NO**.

Is there a reason why this isn't evaluating when it seems it should? https://regex101.com/r/urbepW/1

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example in the [Predicate Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html), it looks like `MATCHES` requires the regexp to match the entire string, not just part of it. So you need to have `.*` at the beginning and end to match anywhere in the string.

```
NSString *re = @".*Geo.*";
```